# Socket IO Swift Client add authentication headers after connection

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

Using the [Socket.IO swift client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift), how can you add headers, such as authorization headers *after* connection? Currently when configuring a client, you can provide options for `connectParams` and `extraHeaders`, both of which are only sent on the initial connection.

I want to connect a client, have the client call an authentication method on the server, receive a token back, and THEN attach that token to all future socket emits but it doesn't seem like there's a way to do that.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may emit another event right after connection, which contains your authentication data;

```
socket.on("connect") { data, ack in
    socket.emitWithAck("authenticate", token).timingOut(after: 0, callback: { dataArray in

    })
}
```

and then you can authenticate or drop the connection on the server side.